# lazyload() breaks jQuery Mobile changePage and navigate in iOS phonegap

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-lazyload

The conflict between lazyload and jquery mobile breaks the expected results of using `$.mobile.changePage` and `$.mobile.navigate` in phonegap iOS builds.

It works in Desktop browsers though, but not on iOS builds (such as those phonegap provides).

The issue is caused by this section of code:

```
/* With IOS5 force loading images when navigating with back button. */
        /* Non optimal workaround. */
        if ((/iphone|ipod|ipad.*os 5/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
            $window.bind("pageshow", function(event) {
                if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
                    elements.each(function() {
                        $(this).trigger("appear");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

With the problem in the stack trace being `event.originalEvent` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Following patch would fix the problem. However this has also been fixed in the latest version of the plugin.

```
if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.persisted) {
    elements.each(function() {
        $(this).trigger("appear");
    });
}
```